# LPeg alternative match?

Tags: parsing, lua

Looking over the LPeg docs I do not see a way to have alternatives(OR)

http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg

e.g., a | b will match a or b. Am I missing something?

Comment: This question belongs on [so], it has no real relationship with TeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation you linked to, we can read that [`patt1 + patt2`](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/#op-add) matches `patt1` or `patt2`, in this order.

Something like the following should work (but I'm no LuaTeX expert).

```
\def\test#1{%
  \directlua{
    require('lpeg');
    tex.print(lpeg.match(lpeg.S('0123456789')+lpeg.P(3),'#1'))
}}
\test{123}
\test{abc}
```

Probably `'#1'` should be replaced by the appropriate LuaTeX primitive to escape `#1` properly.

Comment: I don't follow your code. I do not want an *ordered* match but an **unordered** match. I think the '-' symbol does the job but not sure(the description given on the site is a little strange but may be equivalent to OR).

Comment: There is no such thing as an unordered OR.  Here, "ordered" denotes the fact that first `patt1` is tested, _then_ if the first one failed, `patt2` is tried.  This is identical to the `|` of regular expressions in Perl 5, and most other regular expression engines, but not to POSIX-compliant engines.

Comment: huh? | is OR in all regular expressions I know of. (a | b | c) will match any one of a b or c. From wiki: `"A vertical bar separates alternatives. For example, gray|grey can match "gray" or "grey"."` Note the order does not matter. i.e., **unordered**!

Comment: @Uiy The order does not matter if the only question is "is there a match?"  However, the order is important when your goal is to extract submatches.  For instance, most regex engines searching for `(ab|abc)` in `abcd` will capture `ab`, but exchanging the two branches will give `abc`.  One notable exception is Perl 6: I believe it returns the longest match, but the details are more complicated.

Comment: Yes, and you've proved your answer is wrong. ab + abc would require ababc to match yet you have said ab + abc(ab | abc) should return ab. lPeg uses - for "or" so ab - abc will first try to match abc then if it fails it will try to match ab so it will either return abc or ab on a match.

Comment: @Uiy: I beg to differ.  As is documented, `lpeg.P('ab')+lpeg.P('abc')` will first try to match `ab`, and if this fails, try to match `abc` (of course, with those particular patterns, the second one will never match).  On the other hand, `lpeg.P('ab')-lpeg.P('abc')` will match `ab`, unless it is followed by `c`, in which case it will fail to match.  What you describe, _concatenation_, is achieved with `*`.  Namely, `lpeg.P('ab')*lpeg.P('abc')` is equivalent to `lpeg.P('ababc')`.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. You mean it will try to match the first then try to match second if the first fails. I was thinking you meant that it will match the first then the second(basically *). It was a communication failure(probably mainly on my part). Anyways, I wrote some lpeg code for reference that can be used to checking these things.

Comment: BTW, `"Matches patt1 or patt2 (ordered choice)"` Is what is confusing. My ordered choice they simply mean that the first match is returned first. To me this is obvious(although it could be switched that wouldn't be natural). To me this is an unordered match and corresponds to the boolean **OR** operator which also corresponds to `+`. **AND** = `*` and so the syntax is natural but different from what usually is used to define grammars. In EBNF `+` is used for **AND** while here it is used for **OR**

Comment: Bruno: Ok, a * b * c returns an ordered match required abc. I would like to create a pattern that matches any permutation of abc too. In standard algebra 3*4*5 = 4*3*5 = 5*4*3 = ....ie, * is commutative. I would like a similar feature in lpeg. I can achieve the same result by mixing * and + but because of the number of patterns I'm trying to match the code goes up exponentially. e.g., how many ways can one write the product of 3,4,5,6,7? 5!

Comment: @Uiy: I think it is hard to do this if you want to enforce that each appears exactly or at most once.  If you don't mind a pattern appearing several times, you can do something like `(a+b+c+d)^0`.  You might have more luck finding Lua experts on StackOverflow.

Comment: (a+b+c+d)^0 allows many repetitions. So we could have aaaaa or ababcd or any string of any combination of a,b,c,d

Comment: Yes, so perhaps `^-4` would suit your needs better, but again, this is not quite what you want.  I don't see a way to get permutations easily using a grammar: the best I see is to go down from n! to n*2^n roughly.  For each subset E of `{1,...,n}`, add a rule `E = 1*E\{1} + 2*E\{2} +...`, where `E\{1}` is `E` without the element `1`, and the right hand side should have one term per element in E, covering the case where matching E starts by matching that element.

Comment: It shouldn't be difficult. One just needs to keep a counter. Obviously a permutation only allows one of each. By just counting how many time each one occurs you can easily do it. It has to be built into the parser though. e.g., (a^-1 | b^-2 | c^-1 | d^-3) could mean that we allow at most 1 a in a match, 2 b's, 1 c, and 3 d's. Most grammars already use counters so it is not difficult.

Comment: @Uiy: I think LPEG is implemented using a packrat parser (that's the normal way of parsing PEGs).  Packrat parsers are very fast, but cannot support the most general grammars.  In fact, I'm starting to get convinced that a packrat parser recognizing exactly all permutations of 1,...,N would need to be of size exponential in N.  ---  The situation is somewhat similar to how 'true' regular expressions can be recognized by automata, but the construction `a{13,57}` requires an automaton with 57 states, and some constructions cannot be implemented at all.

Comment: You may be right. I believe that parsing permutations requires a context sensitive grammar to do efficiently. But I do not think it would be difficult to modify a context free grammar to support it. Again, it just involves keeping a counter. You are right that a naive approach is to use all the permutations as individual patterns which will require n! Effectively the pattern is exponential and there is no way around that. This does not mean, of course, that it is impossible or hard to do.

Comment: We can compute all the permutations of a set quite easily. In fact, one simple way to do this is to write a function in lpeg that takes n patterns and creates all the permutations and returns this super pattern that will match any of them. This would work BUT is extremely inefficient. `Since we are only checking for a permutation rather than trying to generate them it is much easier`. It is extremely easy to see if x is a permutation of abcd rather than generate all permutation of abcd. It is analogous to checking is a string matches a grammar verses generating all possible valid string..

Comment: Writing a function to generate one pattern per permutations is straightforward indeed, but as you say, unnecessarily slow.  I believe the correct approach given the tools at hand is to use lpeg to grab an arbitrary combination of abcd (with repetition), then check that it is a permutation.  For this to work, the patterns must be disjoint: searching for permutations of `a`, `b`, `ab`, `ba`, `bb`, and `aa` by matching `(P"a"+P"b"+P"ab"+P"ba"+P"bb"+P"aa")^-6` then doing a check would fail, and this holds for any ordering of the six branches of the or.

Comment: @Uiy  I think any parser which recognizes exactly permutations of those six strings is going to do an exponential amount of back-tracking, or is going to memoize an exponential amount of memory.  I don't have a proof, but I wouldn't be surprised if "recognize if a string contains a permutation of N strings" is NP-complete: once we have the splitting into substrings, of course, checking it is linear, but finding such a splitting would, I guess, be "hard".  In your situation, the various substrings are "independent" in some sense, so the approach of matching then checking should work.

Comment: I disagree. I think, at least for simple patterns(one that do not contain potential similar sub-patterns) is very easy using counters. The problem with your case is that it still grows exponentially in code. In my case it is not so much how fast the parser takes but how easy it is to write in code. I could generate all permutations by hand and stick in the code like abcd + abdc + adbc + adcb + bacb + badc + bdac + bdca + .... but it is very time consuming. The performance issue is the other part of the problem of course.

Comment: Now the above permutations are: `Perm(abcd) = a*perm(bcd) + b*perm(acd) + c*perm(abd) + d*perm(abc)` = `a*perm(b*perm(cd) + c*perm(bd) + d*perm(bc) + ...` So it is quite easy to define permutations of patterns in lpeg recursively. I think if you look at the decomposition you can see that by using counters we can break out of the recursion much sooner and not traverse most cases. It would be a significant performance boost.

Comment: @Uiy The problem is that counters cannot be implemented in a packrat parser, except by adding one state per value of the counter (or per set of values in your case since you need one counter per letter).  Of course, this can be optimized by only creating states when they are needed, but you would have to hack the internals of the peg quite a bit.  This is similar to regexes parsed using an automaton: to recognize `a{13,37}` you need 37 states in the automaton.  Those states could be added on the fly, but that's not so easy to code in a fully robust and general way.  Doable, I agree.

Comment: No, you don't need one counter per variable because you can "linearize" them. For example, suppose we are trying to parse all the permutations of abcd. You may think we need 4 counters but we could use one. Suppose we only allow a max of 4. Then a adds 1, b adds 5, c adds 25, d adds 225. Any permutation of abcd will have the same numerical value(since addition is commutative) = 1 + 5 + 25 + 225 = 256 BUT aaaa = 4, abbb = 16, and any repetition will be a different value and will not be 256(By design). This only requires one "counter".

Comment: Yes (probably more efficient using 2 rather than 5 since the max number of repetitions for each substring is 1). But you get one state per value of the counter, so regardless of whether you implement it as 1 counter or 4 counters, you get the same number of states required in the worst case.  The reason you can't avoid get so many states is that a packrat parser works by memoizing results, saving the information of whether (and how) it matched a given grammar rule at a given spot in the string.  Since in effect you have 2^N grammar rules, that may lead to O(2^N) memory cost (worst case).

Comment: @Uiy On the other hand, it is true that with non-ambiguous substrings, you the packrat parser will only use O(N) memory or so, since only one of the 2^N possible branches will be explored.

Comment: Right, BUT since lpeg is greedy there shouldn't be any ambiguous strings. e.g., if we had some grammar like s = V"a" | P"b" | P"c" and a = P"a"^0 then it would match any permutation of (a...a)bc like aaabc caaaab etc because the a rule is ready and will consume all the repetitive a's. So while aaaabc is not a permutation of abc in the traditional sense it is a permutation consider our grammar. now if we make s = P"a"^0 + V"a" | P"b" | P"c" then a...abc will not match because the first rule, P"a"^0 will consume all the a's resulting in bc left which is not a permutation of abc.

Comment: The point being is that there shouldn't be any issues with ambiguity since all lowest level rules will be matched first. e.g., is aaaabc = (aaa)abc or = (aaaa)bc. Because lpeg is greedy we know the answer and the the input does not end with a permutation of abc(enough though it looks like it at first glance).